# run jar in php without shell_exec() and exec()

Tags: php, jar, exec, shell-exec

i have a code

```
<?php
   if (isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])) {
      $url = ' http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.escapeshellarg($_GET['_escaped_fragment_']);
      $result = shell_exec('java -jar htmlunit.jar'.$url);
      echo $result;
   }
?>
```

when i try to run it, i see an error

```
Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons
```

with exec() the same

```
Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons
```

My hosting can't change php.ini for me.

How can i ran jar?

Comment: Not going to happen. The wrapper classes have been disabled. You have no access to execute from the CLI. Your only option is to make a cURL request to another server that CAN execute this and return the result to you.

Comment: Your hosting company has disabled this functions for security reasons. This is common in a shared hosting environment. If you need to execute shell commands from your PHP site, you'll need to upgrade your plan to a root- or v-server.